# EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file folder permission issue

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to run a Maintenance Cleanup Task to remove .bak files older than 2 days (simple enough).

Been trying all variety of .bak, BAK, .*., and editing the path, but the files are still not getting removed even though I receive a "job succeeded" log message.

I'm not at the point where I believe it's a folder permission issue.

How do I make sure my SA has the proper permissions to remove files from a folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the domain (or local) Windows account that the SQL Server and the SQL Server Agent services run under have the rights needed to delete the files.